# Python+Selenium: AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != ["'This[99 chars] that\\n you give the Sto[183 chars]it."]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, magento, magento2

**Information**

In my current project I work in the Magento Cloud area, and define my test cases using Python + Selenium. Currently I used Chrome with the webdriver 78x in the first development stage.

On the page is a block with text that I try to verify. The source works correctly according to one view, I just define an assert at the end which secures the VErification.

But now the problem, the assert becomes active every time, although the text is correct. I can't really explain this anymore.

I get the following message:

```
     self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
    AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != ["'This[99 chars] that\\n you give the Sto[183 chars]it."]

    Second list contains 1 additional elements.
    First extra element 0:
    "'This[99 chars] that\\n you give the Store while using this we[441 chars]ges.' != 'This[99 chars] that you give the Store while using this webs[431 chars]ges.'\nDiff is 1188 characters long. Set self.maxDiff to None to see it."

    - []
    + ["'This[99 chars] that\\n you give the Store while using this we[441 "
    +  "chars]ges.' != 'This[99 chars] that you give the Store while using this "
    +  "webs[431 chars]ges.'\n"
    +  'Diff is 1188 characters long. Set self.maxDiff to None to see it.']

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 11 tests in 117.076s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

**The Source**

```
def test_untitled_test_case(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://URL-TO-PROJECT.com")
    self.assertEqual("This privacy policy sets out how this website (hereafter \"the Store\") uses and protects any information that\n you give the Store while using this website. The Store is committed to ensuring that your privacy is protected.\n Should we ask you to provide certain information by which you can be identified when using this website, then\n you can be assured that it will only be used in accordance with this privacy statement. The Store may change\n this policy from time to time by updating this page. You should check this page from time to time to ensure\n that you are happy with any changes.", driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Privacy and Cookie Policy'])[3]/following::p[1]").text)
```

**question**

Am I correct that my query is wrong?

Am I asking too much text?

Is it Magento?

[image]

Comment: What is `assertEqual()`?

Comment: A definition can be found here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

Comment: How is `self.verificationErrors` defined?

Comment: driver = self.driver
        driver.get("e")
        try: self.assertEqual("TEXT.", driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Privacy and Cookie Policy'])[3]/following::p[1]").text)
        except AssertionError as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))

Comment: You are masking the assertion error thrown from comparing the strings, remove the `except AssertionError`. In the example you provided you are asserting `"TEXT."` is equals to the site content, which is obviously false.

Comment: I'll try that, of course, thanks for the tip. But is a faulty text still verified?

Comment: Yes, in the assert. The error message in the question shows you are checking `verificationErrors` against an empty list, not checking the strings.

Comment: I have tried your tip and accordingly the Except taken out, also the try. But I still get the error message.

Comment: Try getting the inner text of the element you are identifying in Selenium. It looks like you may be trying to compare a web object to a string, so grabbing the inner text of the web element should resolve your issue. [Here's a resource](http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2017/07/17/all-about-gettext-method-what-why-and-how/)

Comment: In your assert, try `.text.strip()` instead of just `.text`. Does that work? It looks like from your error message that the second item you are comparing has two items where the first one only has one. I'm wondering if the carriage return and whitespace at the start of the `.text` string is causing the issue. If this doesn't work, try adding an assert to something simple/shorter like "Privacy and Cookie Policy" and see if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately no, no change